# How do I connect js files to Gulp?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

I'm trying to figure out Gulp and I ran into this problem: .The js file is uploaded to dist, but the file script does not run, and HTML and CSS are displayed normally. Tell me, please, what is the error?

.js

```
console.log('Hello');
```

gulpfile.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack-stream');
gulp.task('js', function(){
    return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(
    'clean',
    gulp.parallel('html', 'sass', 'images', 'js'),
    gulp.parallel('server', 'watch')
));
```

webpack.config.js

```
const config = {

mode: 'production',

entry: {
    index: './src/js/index.js',
},

output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
    ],
},
```

}

module.exports = config;

And in index.html I'm connecting the script

```
<scrip src="./js/index.bundle.js"></scrip>
```

Everything starts, but the string 'Hello' is not output in the console. Here is the result

[image]

Comment: The tag is `<script>` not `<scrip>`